# Query to return Count using QtSql

Tags: sqlite, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, qtsql

How can I execute the following query using the QtSql library?

```
const QString createQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movies;";
```

I tried the following code, but that returns a bool.

```
QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.setDatabaseName("/path/to/database");
QSqlQuery query(database);

query.exec(createQuery);//returns bool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` function *does* execute the query; that's what it return value says.

To read the returned value, navigate to the first returned row, then get the value from the first column:

```
query.first();
count = query.value(0).toInt();
```

The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html) might be helpful.